# proxy server with python

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

i have an university project with python which i have to write a proxy server that waits for a request from a client and then connects the client to the server. i searched the net and found an already-written code from this site:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-proxy-webserver-in-python-set-1/

so i used it and made some changes in the code and add the public server and port to it
but when i run it i get this error:

> line 33, in main 
> request = conn.recv(4096) 
> NameError: name 'conn' is not defined

so i'm not very familiar with sockets and python so if there are obvious mistakes in the code i would be happy if u guys could explain them in a very basic way so my amateur butt would understand it lol 
this is the code:

```
import signal
import socket
import threading

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        # creating a tcp socket
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # reuse the socket
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.ip = 'localhost'
        self.port = 8080
        self.serverSocket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.serverSocket.listen(10)
        self.__clients = {}

    def shutdown(self):
        # shutdown on cntrl c
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.shutdown)

    def multirequest (self):

        while True:
            # establish the connection
            (clientSocket, client_address) = self.serverSocket.accept()

            d = threading.Thread(name=self._getclientname(client_address),
                                 target=self.proxy_thread,
                                 args=(clientSocket, client_address))
            d.setDaemon(True)
            d.start()

    def main(self, conn):
        # get the request from browser
        request = conn.recv(4096)

        # parse the first line
        first_line = request.split('\n')[0]

        # get url
        url = first_line.split(' ')[1]

        http_pos = url.find("://")
        if http_pos == -1:
            temp = url
        else:
            temp = url[(http_pos + 3):]

        webserver = ""
        port = -1
        port_pos = temp.find(":")

        # find end of web server

        webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
        if webserver_pos == -1:
            webserver_pos = len(temp)

        if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos:

            # default port
            port = 80
            webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]

        else:  # specific port
            port = int((temp[(port_pos + 1):])[:webserver_pos - port_pos - 1])
            webserver = temp[:port_pos]

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((webserver, port))
        s.sendall(request)

        while 1:
            # receive data from web server
            data = s.recv(4096)

            if len(data) > 0:
                conn.send(data)  # send to browser/client

            else:
                break
p = Proxy()
p.main()
```

Comment: Looking at your code, nothing is calling the `__init__` function ( that is very odd, that is the common initializator for an object, not on a module)

Answer (score 0):

In python, the common pattern for executables is like this:

```py
def main():  # Or whatever name you want to use
   """Your code here"""

# If you are importing the code, the condition will evaluate to false.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Have in mind that you can use whatever function name you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside of a class like this. Any variables you plan to use through your code, define inside of the `__init__` method, this could be for example your `self.serverSocket`, ip, port number, etc.

The init method is deigned to run once, once you create an instance of the class, it usually stores variables. The main method or any other methods you define, would be where you put the rest of your code.

```
import signal
import socket
import threading

class proxy():
    def __init__(self):
        # creating a tcp socket
        self.serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # reuse the socket
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        self.your_ip = "127.0.0.1" # loop back address
        self.your_port = 80 # use a port thats open like port 80

    def shutdown(self):
        # add your signal shutdown code here
        pass

    def main(self):
        # shutdown on cntrl c
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.shutdown)

        self.serverSocket.bind((self.your_ip, self.your_port))

        self.serverSocket.listen(10)
        self.__clients = {}

        while True:
            # establish the connection
            (clientSocket, client_address) = self.serverSocket.accept()

            d = threading.Thread(name=self._getClientName(client_address),
                                 target=self.proxy_thread,
                                 args=(clientSocket, client_address))
            d.setDaemon(True)
            d.start()

        # get the request from browser
        request = conn.recv(4096)

        # parse the first line
        first_line = request.split('\n')[0]

        # get url
        url = first_line.split(' ')[1]

        http_pos = url.find("://")
        if http_pos == -1:
            temp = url
        else:
            temp = url[(http_pos + 3):]

        port_pos = temp.find(":")

        # find end of web server
        webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
        if webserver_pos == -1:
            webserver_pos = len(temp)

        webserver = ""
        port = -1

        if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos:

            # default port
            port = 80
            webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]

        else:  # specific port
            port = int((temp[(port_pos + 1):])[:webserver_pos - port_pos - 1])
            webserver = temp[:port_pos]

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((webserver, port))
        s.sendall(request)

        while 1:
            # receive data from web server
            data = s.recv(4096)

            if len(data) > 0:
                conn.send(data)  # send to browser/client

            else:
                break

p = proxy()
p.main()
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answer i did what you said and made a few changes but still my code is not running and now i have another problem which is:
1. Unresolved attribute reference in line 27 and 28
2. TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conn'

Comment: it says the attributes _getClientName and proxy_thread are unresolved

Answer (score 0):

I successful make a local python proxy via socket module: https://github.com/wayne931121/Python_Proxy_Server/blob/main/Proxy.py

It can run http and https request.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


# 參考資料
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218058/python-https-proxy-tunnelling
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008233/proxy-server-with-python/73851150#73851150

import sys
#import ssl
import time
import signal
import socket
#import certifi
import threading

with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("")

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('Proxy is Stopped.')
    sys.exit(0)

def write(*content, prt=False):
    if prt : 
        if len(content[0])<100:
            print(*content)
        else:
            print("This message is too long not print in cmd but will store at log.txt.")
    if type(content[0])==bytes:
        content = b" ".join(content)
    else:
        content = bytes(" ".join(content), encoding="utf-8")
    with open("log.txt", "ab") as f:
        f.write(content+b"\n")  

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # creating a tcp socket
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # reuse the socket
        self.ip = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 8080
#         self.host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())+":%s"%self.port
        self.sock.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(10)
        print("Proxy Server Is Start, See log.txt get log.")
        print("Press Ctrl+C to Stop.")
        start_multirequest = threading.Thread(target=self.multirequest)
        start_multirequest.setDaemon(True)
        start_multirequest.start()
        while 1:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    
    def multirequest(self):
        while True:
            (clientSocket, client_address) = self.sock.accept() # establish the connection
            client_process = threading.Thread(target=self.main, args=(clientSocket, client_address))
            client_process.setDaemon(True)
            client_process.start()
            
    def main(self, client_conn, client_addr): # client_conn is the connection by proxy client like browser.
        origin_request = client_conn.recv(4096)
        request = origin_request.decode(encoding="utf-8") # get the request from browser
        first_line = request.split("\r\n")[0] # parse the first line
        url = first_line.split(" ")[1] # get url
        http_pos = url.find("://")
        if http_pos == -1:
            temp = url
        else:
            temp = url[(http_pos + 3):]
        webserver = ""
        port = -1
        port_pos = temp.find(":")
        webserver_pos = temp.find("/") # find end of web server
        if webserver_pos == -1:
            webserver_pos = len(temp)
        if port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos: # default port
            port = 80
            webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]
        else: # specific port
            port = int(temp[(port_pos + 1):])
            webserver = temp[:port_pos]
        write("Connected by", str(client_addr))
        write("ClientSocket", str(client_conn))
        write("Browser Request:")
        write(request)
        server_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_conn.settimeout(1000)
        try:
            server_conn.connect((webserver, port)) # "server_conn" connect to public web server, like www.google.com:443.
        except: # socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
            client_conn.close()
            server_conn.close()
            return
        if port==443:
            client_conn.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n")
            client_conn.setblocking(0)
            server_conn.setblocking(0)
            write("Connection established")
            # now = time.time()
            client_browser_message = b""
            website_server_message = b""
            error = ""
            while 1:
                # if time.time()-now>1: # SET TIMEOUT
                    # server_conn.close()
                    # client_conn.close()
                    # break
                try:
                    reply = client_conn.recv(1024)
                    if not reply: break
                    server_conn.send(reply)
                    client_browser_message += reply
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
                    # error += str(e)
                try:
                    reply = server_conn.recv(1024)
                    if not reply: break
                    client_conn.send(reply)
                    website_server_message += reply
                except Exception  as e:
                    pass
            # error += str(e)
            write("Client Browser Message:")
            write(client_browser_message+b"\n")
            write("Website Server Message:")
            write(website_server_message+b"\n")
            # write("Error:")
            # write(error+"\n")
            server_conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            server_conn.close()
            client_conn.close()
            return
        server_conn.sendall(origin_request)
        write("Website Host Result:")
        while 1:
            # receive data from web server
            data = server_conn.recv(4096)
            try:
                write(data.decode(encoding="utf-8"))
            except:
                write(data)
            if len(data) > 0:
                client_conn.send(data)  # send to browser/client
            else:
                break
        server_conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        server_conn.close()
        client_conn.close()
Proxy()
```